# identifier expected cannot figure out why or how to fix

Tags: java, class

Constantly getting " expected
import auq.;" for these lines and cannot figure out why.

```
import ats.;
import auq.;
import avf.;
import awb.;
import bcx.;
import bjy.;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `.` or need to put a specific class or package name after that. This is not valid:

```
import ats.;
```

It should be either of these forms:

```
import ats.*;  // to import all the types from ats package
import ats.specifiClass; // to import a specific type from the ats package
```

Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: when I remove the "." I get the error "." expected

Comment: @user2780680 have u tried to use the alternatives i mentioned with * or a specific class?